# I keep getting errors on SQL Server - String & Binary Data truncation, Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

I am new to SQL and SQL Server. I am trying to implement a small database. However, I keep getting three errors.

Error #1:

> String or binary data would be truncated

Error #2:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint   "FK__Formation__Locat__25869641"

Error #3:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__DATA__Classifica__2B3F6F97".

I've tried a variety of different changes and nothing seems to work. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE Location 
(
    LocationID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    LocationName VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (LocationID)    
);

CREATE TABLE Formation 
(
    FormationID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    FormationName VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
    RockType VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
    LocationID INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (FormationID),
    FOREIGN KEY (LocationID) REFERENCES Location(LocationID)    
);

CREATE TABLE Classification 
(
    ClassificationID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    ClassificationType VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
    ClassificationDescription VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
    FormationID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (ClassificationID),
    FOREIGN KEY (FormationID) REFERENCES Formation(FormationID)
);

CREATE TABLE DATA 
(
    FossilID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    FossilName VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
    FossilType VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
    CatalogueDate DATE NOT NULL,
    ClassificationID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (FossilID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ClassificationID) REFERENCES Classification(ClassificationID)
);

INSERT INTO Location 
VALUES ('001', 'Montana');

INSERT INTO Formation 
VALUES ('R01', 'Hell Creek Formation', 'Cretaceous', 001);

INSERT INTO Classification 
VALUES ('001', 'Saurischia', 'Brachiosauridae', 'Hell Creek Formation');

INSERT INTO DATA 
VALUES ('F01', 'Brachiosaurus', 'Vertebrae', '01/MAY/2017', '001');
```

Comment: As a general best practice, you should *always* specify the columns you're inserting into - so use this instead of what you have now: `INSERT INTO Location (LocationID, LocationName) VALUES ('001', 'Montana');`

Comment: Also: datatypes of column involved in a FK relationship *should be the same* - your `Location.LocationID` is `CHAR(5)`, but the `Formation.LocationID` referencing it is `INT` - make up your mind, use the **same** datatype for all! And since an `ID` typically *is* a numeric value - use a **numeric** datatype - `INT`, `BIGINT` etc. - do **not** store numeric values as `CHAR(5)` !!

Answer (score 2):

`INT` <> `VARCHAR(5)` <> `CHAR(5)`. Column should be the same type:

```
CREATE TABLE Location (
LocationID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
LocationName VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (LocationID)    
);

CREATE TABLE Formation (
FormationID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
FormationName VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
RockType VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL, 
LocationID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,               -- here
PRIMARY KEY (FormationID),
FOREIGN KEY (LocationID) REFERENCES Location(LocationID)    
);

CREATE TABLE Classification (
ClassificationID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
ClassificationType VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
ClassificationDescription VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
FormationID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,                 -- here
PRIMARY KEY (ClassificationID),
FOREIGN KEY (FormationID) REFERENCES Formation(FormationID)
);

CREATE TABLE DATA (
FossilID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
FossilName VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
FossilType VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
CatalogueDate DATE NOT NULL,
ClassificationID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (FossilID),
FOREIGN KEY (ClassificationID) REFERENCES      Classification(ClassificationID)
);
```

**[DBFiddleDemo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=46784d4d5c5d4dbd516a46a40d93a067)**

---

And your insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO Location VALUES ('001', 'Montana');
INSERT INTO Formation VALUES ('R01', 'Hell Creek Formation', 'Cretaceous', '001');  --corrected
INSERT INTO Classification VALUES ('001', 'Saurischia', 'Brachiosauridae', 'R01');   --corrected
INSERT INTO DATA VALUES ('F01', 'Brachiosaurus', 'Vertebrae', '01/MAY/2017', '001');
```

Truncation error `'Hell Creek Formation'` cannot fit `CHAR(5)`. You need to refer PK. Also consider using:

```
INSERT INTO tab(col_name1, col_name2, ...)
VALUES(...)
```